# Will C++17 allow forward declaration of nested classes?

Tags: c++, c++17

Not sure where to ask (feel free to close this if it is an inappropriate question) but I have not found anything on this specifically in C++17 proposals, neither [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4230.html) or [this](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/11/updates-to-my-trip-report) mentions it when dealing with the nested namespace addition to C++.

So currently this is the only option:

```
class A 
{
public: 
    class B; //forward-declared INSIDE class/namespace
};

class A::B //defined outside
{
};
```

Will this be possible in C++17?

```
class A::B; //forward declared NESTED outside of parent class/namespace

class C
{
    A::B *b;
};
```

and then either this (1) (as seems to be the proposal of nested namepsace definitions)

```
class A::B //definition of A::B without defining A
{

};
```

or this (2)

```
class A
{
public:
    class A::B
    {

    };
};
```

or this [3]

```
class A
{
public:
    class B;
};

class A::B
{
};
```

I suspect the definition of `A::B` without defining `A` first might not work though (although the proposal seems to allow it).

Comment: *class*es are much different from *namespace*s. But see [P0289](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0289r0.pdf).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a proposal on the issue titled `Forward declarations of nested classes` [P0289R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0289r0.pdf). However as you can see from the last [Trip Report: C++ Standards Meeting in Jacksonville, February 2016](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2016/03/21/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-jacksonville-february-2016/), this proposal was pendent to proposals for which further work is encouraged. I'm quoting the verdict of the committee (**Emphasis Mine**):

> This would allow things like `X::A*` to appear in a header without
>   requiring a definition for `X` to also appear in the header
>   (forward-declarations of `X` and `X::A` will be sufficient). **EWG found the
>   use case compelling**, because currently a lot of class definitions to
>   appear in headers only because interfaces defined in the header use
>   pointers or references to nested classes of the type. **Several details
>   still need to be worked out**. (For example, what happens if a
>   definition of `X` does not appear in any other translation unit (TU)?
>   What happens if a definition of `X` appears in another TU, but does not
>   define a nested `class A`? What happens if it does define a nested class
>   A, but it’s private? The answer to some or all of these may have to be
>   “ill-formed, no diagnostic required”, because diagnosing errors of
>   this sort would require significant linker support.)

Comment: I might be mistaken but the raised questions seem to be answered. Even if it was first adopted as more restrictive version it would be of great benefit and can be relaxed in later standards if it turns out ok. I think the bigger concern might be the lost properties mentioned in the paper - namely the fact that saying X::A does currently automatically also mean definition and (therefore) does not incur any name lookup. However I find it an acceptable price. Hopefully it will yet be all worked out and this proposal makes it into final C++17!

Comment: @Resurrection Fortunately or unfortunately whether the raised questions have been answered or not it's up to the C++ committee to decide :). Personally, I hope this proposal will make it to C++17 as I find it useful and in general I think that forward declaration of nested classes is a hole in the language that must be closed.

Comment: I don't understand their concerns, don't you get the exact same issues with a classic forward declaration? You now can forward declare a class that does not exist, or is in a namespace you did not specify at forward declaration etc.

Comment: How about C++20? Did this make it into C++20 at least?

Comment: Is there a way to upvote P0289R0 ?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO lacking the ability to do forward deceleration of classes is a major hole in C++ language definition, which results in people using void* where a forward reference would be more safe.

Here is a workaround using namespaces:

1. Flatten the class structure you need to pre-declare
2. Use namespaces to separate the code
3. Do the forward deceleration using the namespaces

```
namespace ns1 {
namespace ns2 {  

typedef class C * cptr_t; // declare both class and a pointer type
}}

ns1::ns2::C *cp;      // use forward deceleration of the class
ns1::ns2::cptr_t cp;  // use the typedef
```

This workaround does not solve the problem properly but may help in some situations.